# Creating sublist from indices

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, sublist

Is it possible to create a sublist from another list, using only the element indices?
I'm looking for nice solution e.g. lambdas, streams from Java 8.

For example (pseudocode):

```
a = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = a.getByIndices([0, 2, 4, 5, 3])
print(b) // [10, 8, 6, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Of course it's *possible*. I can think of how to do it with a for-loop, but I don't have anything to say about streams.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I thought about using filter, but then I have to call indexOf and check if index is in indices list. I think it's not efficient solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have the following method:

```
private static <T> List<T> getByIndices(List<T> list, List<Integer> indexes) {
    return indexes.stream().map(list::get).collect(toList());
}
```

This creates a `Stream` from the given indexes, maps to the element of the list at the index and collect the result to a list.

Sample usage:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 5, 3);
System.out.println(getByIndices(list, indexes)); // prints [10, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

For arrays of ints you could use this:

```
int[] b = IntStream.of(0, 2, 4, 5, 3)
      .map(i -> a[i])
      .toArray();
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't compile since there is no varargs version in the `Arrays` class... You need to use `IntStream.of` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Extending [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) is a quick way to get a list implementation up and running. Like the regular [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList-int-int-) method, the following sublist is backed by the main list, so changes to the sublist will write through to the main list (which may or may not be a feature you wanted, but you can always create a new, separate ArrayList from the sublist if needed). Element removal through the sublist is not implemented; it would be doable but require a bit more work.

```
public static <E> List<E> sublistFromIndices(List<E> list, int... indices) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(list);
    Objects.requireNonNull(indices);
    return new AbstractList<E>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return indices.length;
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return list.get(indices[index]);
        }

        @Override
        public E set(int index, E element) {
            return list.set(indices[index], element);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that does what you ask. I can't figure out how to make it lambda function but I'll keep working on it.

```
public static <E> void createSublist(List<E> oldList, List<E> newList, int[] indicies){
        for(int i = 0; i < indicies.length; i++)
             newList.add(oldList.get(indicies[i]));} //Adds indicies to new list
```